# Storing user/password GIT permanent

Tags: git, svn, github, jenkins, keystore

I'm working on Jenkins/Git/Repo jobs. I would like to ask you about git configuration on Jenkins.
Here is my case :
I'm using jenkins in MAC host that has been config Git/SVN/Repo.
In Jenkins I have multiple account for each jobs .
For example
 - for jobs A I'm using account git A for cloning code
 - for jobs B I'm using account SVN B for checkout code

I also added my user into **.gitconfig** file

> [credential]
>       helper = store
>
> [user]
>       name = user
>       email = user@company.net

In **.git-credential** file , the my account information has already added by automatically. Here is the contents:

> https://user:pass@jenkins.host.xxx

My problem is:
If I build job A -> The info account of job B will be clear in **.git-credential**. On the contrary the info account of job A will be clear if I build job A.
Therefor I have to add it again by manual. Its a stupid way.
Please support me if you know .
Thank you so much !

Comment: Even with your additional information (which has now been deleted, as it was posted as an answer), the question is unclear. Are both jobs using the same Git repository *and* the same workspace? It sounds like you're copying workspaces around when you say "the content of .git-credential file will be replaced by Job A's account".  I would remove that file and use the Credentials plugin, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) feature of jenkins to store your username/passwords.

- on the side menu, click *Credentials*

> [image]

- click *Global credentials*

> [image]

- click *Add Credentials*

> [image]

- fill in your username and password and click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button

> [image]

Now in your jenkins jobs, you can pick this credential under the *Repository URL*

> [image]

Comment: Sorry, I have just added the detail of my problem. 
Can you look at it again. Sorry